# Can I have a separate notification sound for my Twitter alerts

Tags: notifications, twitter

As above, I want a different sound for incoming Twitter alerts so they are not the same as my normal texts. It's so frustrating to keep looking at the phone when I am waiting for a particular private text, but I dont want to get rid of my Twitter alerts. Surely like email sound can be different this should be too. How do I do it please? I have an HTC Sensation.

Answer (score 8):

In the Twitter app...

1. Tap the Overflow menu (three vertical dots) and choose "Settings"
2. Tap the account (your username, not general) you want to change
3. Under "Notification Indicators" tap "Ringtone"
4. Choose the Ringtone you want to use for Twitter notifications for this account

For more recent versions of Twitter, this something controlled at the OS level.

1. Long-press the app icon and choose App Info, or go to Android Settings, Apps & notifications, and choose "Twitter"
2. Tap "App notifications"
3. There, for each Twitter account, you can control which notifications you get, whether they make a sound, and whether they also show a pop-up
4. Tap the notification you want to change, make sure "Make sound" is on, and then tap "Sound" to choose the alert ringtone for that notification.

(These instructions are based on Android 8.1 and Twitter 7.40.0.)

Comment: But strangely it is not working. Only default ringtone is getting applied even after I changed it a thousand times.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Twitter Version 7.14.0. There is no overflow menu, and Settings->Notifications has nothing for Ring tone. Android 7.0 on Samsung Galaxy S8+.

Comment: Yep not working. No overflow menu, no username or general section as indicated, only enable sounds effects and this defaults to the system sound. How about posting a screenshot?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe: Do note that this answer is from 2013. The app has obviously changed a lot since then. I'll see if I can add more recent instructions.

Comment: I've added instructions based on Android 8.1 and Twitter 7.40.0. Depending on your OS and app versions, this may vary.